# Hide Border In A Table Based On Conditions In Power BI RB

Tags: powerbi, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

I want to hide border in a table based on conditions like for ex: if I have column X and the values in column X is y,w,z I want to hide border for value Y & W but Z should have border

I tried using an expression but it didn't work I think expressions are not usable in borders so is there a way for this to be achievable ?

Comment: it is doable through the expression, but you can't hide it, but you can change the color to be the same as the background.